# Platform Cache Breaks sfdx retrieve?

Tags: apex, platform-cache

I have added a platform cache partition to my managed package source code:

[image]

I have just added Platform Cache to my package.xml file:

```
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>PlatformCachePartition</name>
</types
```

which now breaks sfdx retrieve??

```
PS C:\Users\Dave2\Documents\Visual Studio Code\TMS> sfdx force:source:retrieve -x .\manifest\package.xml
ERROR running force:source:retrieve:  'undefined' is not valid for the type xsd:double
Preparing retrieve request... done
```

Any thoughts on why adding it would break this process?  Thanks.

Comment: Best guess: Have you explicitly set both the org and session capacity for this partition (even if you're setting one of them to 0)?

Comment: Derek -- Thanks for your help.  Turns out I had a non-display character typo in my package.xml.  All good now.

Answer (score 2):

Look out for non-display characters in the package.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your manifest file is well-formed XML. Look out for non-display/non-printing characters in the file, and also missing XML tags as these can also cause this error.